# How to optimize appending multiple collections to a single list?

Tags: c#

```
foreach (var data in reportdata)
{
   lstReportDataPrint.AddRange(data.ToList());
}
```

1. **reportdata** is IEnumerable type which also contains a collection of records into it.
2. **lstReportDataPrint** is a list.
3. **reportdata** conatins 500 records.

And this loop is taking so much time and i want to reduce it.
I there any other way to do it ?

Comment: Use [the Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/), Luke!

Comment: I would suggest that this question is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if a more complete code sample is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is going to optimize this solution, but you can shrink it to a single line:

```
lstReportDataPrint.AddRange(reportdata.SelectMany(d => d));
```

Note that since [`AddRange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes `IEnumerable<T>`, the call of `ToList()` in your code is unnecessary: it creates a new copy of `List<T>` which is thrown away immediately after the call of `AddRange()`. Avoiding this call should save you some time. However, the most likely reason why the loop underperforms is probably in the code that obtains the data being iterated.

Comment: This is taking more time than foreach

Comment: @user2691432 That is entirely possible. Did you try removing `ToList()` from the call of `AddRange()`?

Comment: Yes i put exactly the same line. It is slightly faster in case of fewer records, but in case of large records it takes much more time than the original time.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that LINQ is great and looks fancy, but it is not very fast due to it working with enumerators. 
Using a for loop and adding each value is actually faster than calling AddRange and using LINQ, eventhough AddRange is optimised for adding a large amount of values.

```
for (int dataID = 0; dataID < reportdata.Count; dataID++)
{
    for (int recordID = 0; recordID < 500; recordID++)
    {
        lstReportDataPrint.Add(reportdata[dataID][recordID]);
    }
}
```

In some tests I run, this nearly halved the execution time compared with LINQ.
This therefor serves as sad reminder that eyecandy and performance are two total different concepts.

Enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

I like the [Parallel.Foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, however you need .Net 4.5 or higher and its not guaranteed to help it run faster. Give it a try

```
Parallel.ForEach(reportdata, (data) =>
{
    lstReportData.AddRange(data.ToList());
});
```

Comment: This assumes that `AddRange` is thread-safe.

Comment: Parallel.ForEach is also taking much more time than foreach.